# Logging to file in seperate directory

Tags: batch-file

Hi there so im making a file that will dir /a in a certain directory then log the file to a file called Log_%random% in my E drive but the thing i have tried this and it doesn't work.

```
@echo off
title Logging
echo --------------------
echo    Dir /a logging
echo --------------------
echo.
echo.
set /p OTUL=Location?:-
cd /d %OTUL%
(
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo %date% %time% 
dir /a
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
)> E:\Other\Test file folder\Vtestbat\di logger\Log_%random%.txt
echo %OTUL%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
echo %date% %time% 
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe_%random%
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
)> log_%random%.txt
```

or

```
set "logfile=log_%random%.txt"
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ >> "%logfile%"
echo %date% %time% >> "%logfile%"
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe_%random% >> "%logfile%"
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ >> "%logfile%"
echo.>> "%logfile%"
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense put it in brackets thx